# How to customize in Exam class the grid from solid lines to dotted lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam, grids

**Problem:** Gray grids disappear or look uneven when copied or printed with our laser printers. Black grids are (re)produced well but look too bold even when the lines are thin.

**Question:**
Is there a possibility to customize in Exam class the grid from solid lines to dotted lines like the grid I created with tikz?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color} \colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.7}
\setlength{\gridsize}{5.03mm}
\setlength{\gridlinewidth}{0.3mm}

\begin{document}

This grid created with \verb|\fillwithgrid{50mm}| \ldots

\fillwithgrid{50mm}

should look like the following grid - or better:

\newcommand{\grid}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=.5cm]
    \tikzset{dashdot/.style={dash pattern=on 0.1mm off 0.9mm on 0.1mm off 0.9mm}}
    \draw[dashdot] (0,0) grid[step=0.5cm] (15,#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\grid{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Why can't you just use your own `\grid` command instead of the class's default command? Is it because some other thing in the class uses `\fillwithgrid` by default, if so that should probably be included in the question.